# Website not shown correctly on some (!) mobile browsers. How to debug?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, cross-browser, vue.js

I created a tool for my personal website based on pagekit and VueJS.
This tool uses `VueJS` on every view.

But: Some users, even with modern web browsers, can use

- `View A` (https://zwergbartagamen-ratgeber.de/das-terrarium/terrarien-rechner)

without problems but on

- `View B` (https://zwergbartagamen-ratgeber.de/das-terrarium/stromrechner)

they see the curly brackets like this `{{ 'Test' | trans }}` (that seems to happen if there is a JS-error and VueJS does not render the page correctly.

The Google Mobile Friendly Test also shows a screenshot with brackets (https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?utm_source=mft&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=mft-redirect&id=EB5-EruTCi74dGdHpbO56A).

Well - on my devices (Apple Macbook with Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi / iPhone with Chrome and Safari) everything works fine.

Can someone of you check, what I'm doing wrong?

If the browsers, who see the curly brackets, would not support VueJS - why are other pages, that are using VueJS, rendered correctly?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You could, for Example, use [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/users/sign_in) to Debug Device / Browser specific Bugs.

Comment: That worked out. I got the error, but now I have to look how to fix that. Thanks for now.